# Better way to SUM previous to next value javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a below array:

```js
[
  {
    "model": "A",
    "count": "10",
    "date": "02-12-2004"
  },
  {
    "model": "B",
    "count": "20",
    "date": "02-01-2004"
  },
  {
    "model": "C",
    "count": "30",
    "date": "02-02-2004"
  }
]
```

I need a new array set to be like the following

```js
[
  {
    "model": "A",
    "count": "10",
    "date": "02-12-2004"
  },
  {
    "model": "B",
    "count": "30",
    "date": "02-01-2004"
  },
  {
    "model": "C",
    "count": "60",
    "date": "02-02-2004"
  }
]
```

It means that all previous set count should be added to the next set.

Comment: This is not how SO works, you have to post some of your code/efforts then only we can help.

Comment: You can share your code, how it can be done.

Comment: We are not here to do you task, we are here to help debug the issue in the code and I don`t see any code in your question.

Comment: Yes sorry it should be 60... i have corrected

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
arr=[{"model":"A", "count":"10","date":"02-12-2004"},{"model":"B", "count":"20","date":"02-01-2004"},{"model":"C", "count":"30","date":"02-02-2004"}]

count=0;
let arr2 = arr.filter(obj=>{
  count+=parseInt(obj.count);
  obj.count=count;
})

console.log(arr)
```

If you dont want to modify the existing array .Use  `Object.assign` method like below

```js
arr=[{"model":"A", "count":"10","date":"02-12-2004"},{"model":"B", "count":"20","date":"02-01-2004"},{"model":"C", "count":"30","date":"02-02-2004"}]

count=0;
let arr2 = arr.map(obj=>{
  count += parseInt(obj.count);
  return Object.assign({}, obj, {
   count:count
  });
});
    
console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: FYI I didn't downvote, but this mutates the original array. You might as well use a `forEach`

Comment: Try logging `arr`. You'll see it has been modified

Comment: @Phil I have added both the ways to do it.